# I'm trying to creat a SSH Key to use in my gitlab but the key file is empty

Tags: gitlab, ssh-keys

I used this command to create the key `ssh-keygen -t ed25519 -C "francielefrederico@gmail.com"` and it was successfully created but when I open the file `~/.ssh/id_ed25519.pub.` to copy the key to my gitlab account, the file is empty.

Comment: can you share the output of `cat ~/.ssh/id_ed25519.pub`

Comment: There should be more prompts after running that first command. Did you see additional prompts and can you update your answer with the output of those? 

One of the prompts let you chose the location of the generated file.
https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ssh/#common-steps-for-generating-an-ssh-key-pair